# Rewriterule alias matching directory name?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

Is it possible to create a rule that matches an existing directory?
As in the following example:

```
RewriteRule ^foo$   foo.php
```

Considering that is also a folder called "foo", Apache tries to open the directory instead of parsing the rule. Is it possible that the rule precedes the directory?

thank you

Testing with the following config:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1
RewriteRule ^foo$   foo.php
```

And receiving the following error from apache: [Fri Mar 07 15:06:34 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/htdocs/www.acasa.org.br.v2/.htaccess: Option MultiViews not allowed here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use **[`-MultiViews`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews)** for it to ignore the folder.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^foo/?$ foo.php [L]
```

You can toggle **[`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash)** on and off with:

```
DirectorySlash Off
```

However the suggested way to resolve your images issue is by using:

```
<base href="http://www.domain.com/" />
```

Comment: After adding -MultiViews Apache is returning an error:
<b>Internal Server Error</b>
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Comment: @fcaserio and what is your entire `.htaccess` content? and what is the error message that shows on the `error_log`? Make sure `foo.php` works.

Comment: The error message on apache log:
[Fri Mar 07 15:08:30 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/htdocs/www.acasa.org.br.v2/.htaccess: Option MultiViews not allowed here.

And this is the .htaccess:
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine on
    AddDefaultCharset iso-8859-1
    RewriteRule ^imprensa$ press_release.php

Comment: @fcaserio can you edit your question with the `.htaccess` properly formatted I can't read it on comment. As for the error message it looks pretty clear to me your hosting does not allow `MultiViews` to be disabled.

Comment: of course. It is updated.
And the apache error is:  [Fri Mar 07 15:08:30 2014] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/htdocs/www.acasa.org.br.v2/.htaccess: Option MultiViews not allowed here

Comment: As for the error message it looks pretty clear to me your hosting does not allow MultiViews to be disabled. So you will need to contact your hosting company to enable it for you so you can turn it on and off as you wish on the `.htaccess`

Comment: I'm actually testing on my development server.
I tested now on the production server and there was no error, but apache is still trying to read the folder.

Comment: @fcaserio I believe because you're missing the `/` see update.

Comment: Well, the thing is the url should be "www.mydomain.com/foo", instead of "www.mydomain.com/foo/". Apache is adding the last "/" when accessing the desired URL. The redirect works in this case, but all image and css references are broken because of the last "/".

Comment: ok, but is that a way apache dont include the "/", or to make apache ignore directory listing on "foo/"? The best solution for the project would be the short URL.

Comment: @fcaserio you could use `DirectorySlash Off` but it may cause you other problems so use at your own risk.